# How to create a HotKey / HotKeys component(s) for Svelte Kit, Svelte, and TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

## How to create a HotKey / HotKeys component(s) for Svelte Kit, Svelte, and TailwindCSS?

I am trying to create a `HotKey` component for Svelte Kit using TailwindCSS for styling. My aim is to capture keypress events and perform some action when a specific key or combination of keys is pressed. However, I'm not sure what's the best way to structure my components and handle keypress events in Svelte. This is in part due to:

- differences across operating systems (e.g. command on Mac being mapped to Meta),
- event propagation,
- user centric design (I don't want to have to know that `'Command'` maps to `'Meta'`,
- best practices (should I use slots?),
- svelte specifics (do I use `window` on both levels of keys?), etc

Can anyone provide an example or suggest a strategy for handling this in the most Svelte idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2):

## How to make `HotKey` & `HotKeys`

You can accomplish this by creating two Svelte components: `HotKey.svelte` and `HotKeys.svelte`.

`HotKey.svelte` is responsible for capturing individual keypress events, while `HotKeys.svelte` listens for events from multiple `HotKey` components and checks if a specific combination of keys has been pressed.

Here's how you can implement these components:

### `HotKey.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">    
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    export let key: string = 'cmd';
    export let value: boolean = false;
    export let debug: boolean = false;

    type KeyMap = {
        [key: string]: string
    }
    type KeyAliasesMap = {
        [key: string]: string[]
    }

    const KeyToHotKey: KeyMap = {
        '⌘': 'Command',
        'cmd': 'Command',
        'meta': 'Meta',

        'control': 'Control',
        'ctrl': 'Control',

        'slash': '/',
    }
    
    const HotKeyAliases:KeyAliasesMap = {
        'Command': ['Command', 'Meta'],
    }

    $: hotKey = KeyToHotKey[key] || key
    $: hotKeyAliases = HotKeyAliases[hotKey] || []
    $: keysToCheck = [hotKey, ...hotKeyAliases]

    const isEventKeyHotKey = (event:KeyboardEvent) => {
        const altKey = event.altKey
        const ctrlKey = event.ctrlKey
        const metaKey = event.metaKey
        const shiftKey = event.shiftKey

        const eventKey = event.key
        const isHotKey = keysToCheck.includes(eventKey)
        if (!isHotKey) return false
        switch (hotKey) {
            case 'Alt':
                return altKey
            case 'Control':
                return ctrlKey
            case 'Meta':
                return metaKey
            case 'Shift':
                return shiftKey        
        }
        return isHotKey
    }

    const handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        const isKeyUp = event.type === 'keyup'
        const isKeyDown = event.type === 'keydown'

        if (debug) console.debug('HotKey <handleKeyPress>\t', {key, hotKey, hotKeyAliases, keysToCheck, event})
        const isKeyPressed = isEventKeyHotKey(event)
        if (isKeyPressed) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (isKeyDown) {
                if (debug) console.debug('HotKey <hot>\t', {key})
                dispatch('hot', {key});
                value = true
            } else {
                if (debug) console.debug('HotKey <not>\t', {key})
                dispatch('not', {key});
                value = false
            }
        }
    }

    const keydown = (event:KeyboardEvent) => {
        handleKeyPress(event)
    }
    const keyup = (event:KeyboardEvent) => {
        handleKeyPress(event)
    }

    const kbd = `
    font-spacemono
    inline-flex place-content-center 
    rounded-lg

    bg-slate-100 border-slate-900 border-2

    group-hover:text-slate-200
    group-hover:border-slate-200
    group-hover:bg-slate-600
    
    px-2 py-1 text-sm
    `
</script>

<svelte:window on:keydown={keydown} on:keyup={keyup}/>
<kbd class="{kbd} {$$props.class}">{key}</kbd>
```

### `HotKeys.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">    
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    import HotKey from '$lib/Layout/HotKey.svelte';
    export let keys: string[] = ['cmd', 'k'];
    export let value: boolean = false;
    export let debug: boolean = false;

    type KeyPressedMap = {
        [key: string]: boolean
    }
    let HotKeyPressedMap: KeyPressedMap = {};
    let KeyPressedMapCount = 0;

    const reset = () => {
        HotKeyPressedMap = {};
        KeyPressedMapCount = 0;
    }

    const hot = (key:string) => {
        if (debug) console.debug('HotKeys <hot>\t', {key, KeyPressedMapCount, HotKeyPressedMap})
        HotKeyPressedMap[key] = true;
        KeyPressedMapCount++;
        KeyPressedMapCount = Math.min(keys.length, KeyPressedMapCount);

        const readyToFire = isComboPressed();
        if (readyToFire) {
            console.log('combo', keys)
            console.log('HotKeys <combo>\t', keys)
            dispatch('hot', key)
            value = true
        }
    }

    const not = (key:string) => {
        if (debug) console.debug('HotKeys <hot>\t', key)
        HotKeyPressedMap[key] = false;
        KeyPressedMapCount--;
        KeyPressedMapCount = Math.max(0, KeyPressedMapCount);
        dispatch('not', key)
        value = false
        reset()
    }

    const isComboPressed = () => {
        const correctNumberOfKeys = KeyPressedMapCount === keys.length;
        const allKeysPressed = keys.every(pressed => HotKeyPressedMap[pressed] === true);
        if (debug) console.debug('isComboPressed\t', {keys, KeyPressedMapCount, HotKeyPressedMap, correctNumberOfKeys, allKeysPressed})
        return correctNumberOfKeys && allKeysPressed;
    }

</script>
<div class="inline-flex {$$props.class}">
{#each keys as key, i}
    <HotKey 
        key={key} 
        class="{i > 0 ? 'ml-0.5' : ''}"
        on:hot={() => hot(key)}
        on:not={() => not(key)}
        {debug}
    >
        {key}
    </HotKey>
{/each}
</div>
```

### Summary

In `HotKey.svelte`, we are capturing the `keydown` and `keyup` events from the window and checking if they match a specified key. If they do, we dispatch a 'hot' or 'not' event, depending on whether the key is pressed or released.

In `HotKeys.svelte`, we listen for these 'hot' and 'not' events from multiple `HotKey` components. When we receive an event, we update our internal state to track which keys are currently pressed. Then, we check if the currently pressed keys match a specified key combination. If they do, we can perform some action.

By using these two components together, you can create complex hotkey combinations in a declarative and reusable way. You can use the `HotKey` component on its own to handle individual hotkeys, or use it inside a `HotKeys` component to handle combinations of keys.

### Example

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import HotKey from '$lib/Layout/HotKey.svelte';
    import HotKeys from '$lib/Layout/HotKeys.svelte';

    const hotkeys = ['⌘', 'k']
    let pressed = false
</script>
{pressed}
<HotKeys keys={hotkeys} bind:value={pressed}></HotKeys>
```

[image: HotKeys component for command and k]

### Notes

- is this the best / most idiomatic way to do this in Svelte? no idea
- should one use slots for `HotKeys.svelte` instead of an `{#each}` block? no idea

#### Bugs

- this triggers (mostly) correctly, however if can get messed up on long key presses. Consider the example above. When I press `⌘` and `k`, then release `k` it will remain `true`. The opposite is *not* true.